# replicating and iterating in R

Tags: r, loops, replicate

This line of code `rep(c(0), 2)`
creates

```
    x
1   0
2   0
```

I would like to somehow extend this, in a way appropriate for R, so that I end up with something like the vector below.  Basically, I'd like to append integers pairwise as such:

```
    x
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   1
5   2
6   2
```

I feel like this is an example of R's dislike of loops which has the unintended side effect of makes simple things seem unfamiliar and makes me long for other tools in other languages, like perhaps numpy in Python.

What is the best way I can iterate and increment in this manner?

Comment: `rep(0:2, each=2)` ?

Comment: `rep` is very powerful, and is such a commonly used function that it's well worth looking at `example(rep)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying Nishanth's answer, this does exactly what you want.

```
rep(0:2, each=2)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data.frame(x = unlist(lapply(0:2, rep, 2)))
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is down-voted. OK, it isn't a very efficient approach, but it produces the correct result.

Comment: Thanks for the support.
To say the truth, an approach like:
     data.frame(x = sort(rep(0:2, each=2)))
should be more efficient

Comment: There's no need for `sort`.

Comment: Ok, I got my problem. I always used "rep" with "times". I never used it with "each". That's why I built that inefficient approach.